# Solr get latest updated / added documents

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a Solr collection which has following fields : event_time, some_field1, some_field2. event_time is a long type. I am looking to see if there is a filter query which can only return documents which have max event_time. There could be more than one documents here.

Comment: Do you provide some more information like the JSON stored in solr or filter query if you have created any

Comment: You should be able to do it by using collapse and expand - https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_7/collapse-and-expand-results.html or the result grouping functionality. sort by the `event_time` field desc and use the first group.

Comment: Another (perhaps more performant option) is to use two queries; one to fetch the max and then retrieve the documents that match afterwards. How many documents do you assume might have the same event_time? Fetching the first ten documents if you're not going to see ten ever and just dropping the ones that doesn't match the first one will be very fast; and if all ten match, make a query to retrieve the first hundred in that case..